# how does globalize3 actually work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize2

Well, I am in the process of internationalising my current project to english and chinese.
Works flawless so far for static content with the i18n gem.

Now I installed globalize3 to translate my products, or, to be more precise, to allow the end-user (shop manager) to translate the products while they are created.

Unfortunately the documentation is a little short for globalize3, so I dont really know how to go about it.

I have now

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   translates :title, :subtitle, :description, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
   #...
end
```

and I created the product_translations table through a migration.

I played around in the console a bit, cause I thought I can now do something like:

```
prods = Product.all
p = prods.first
p.title # works
p.title_en # doesn't work
```

I know it is going to switch by I18n.locale, but the question is how do I add the translations now to the product_translations table. I would like to do it in the same form when creating a new product or editing. Any hints? Thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by using [batch_translations](https://github.com/fidel/batch_translations)